# using tr -t command [comprehension question]

Tags: utilities, tr

When using `tr -t` command, `string1` should be truncated to the length of `string2`, right?

```
tr -t abcdefghijklmn 123          # abc... = string1, 123 = string2
the cellar is the safest place    # actual input
the 3ell1r is the s1fest pl13e    # actual output
```

'to truncate' is another word for 'to shorten', right?`tr` translates, according to the pattern, completely ignoring the `-t` option. If I autocomplete to `--truncate-set1` [to assure that I use the correct option] produces the same output.

**Question**: what am I doing wrong here?

I work in BASH, on a Debian based Distro.

**UPDATE**

*Please note that this is a copy of a comment I made below*

I thought `tr -t` means: *shorten string1 to the length of string2*. I see that `a` is translated to `1`, that `b` would be translated to `2` and that `c` is translated to `3`.
This has nothing to do with shortening. 'To truncate' seems to mean something different than I thought. [I'm no native speaker]

Comment: What other output are you expecting instead? `tr -t abcdefghijklmn 123` is equivalent of `tr abc 123`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? It is hard to understand your question.

Comment: I think you're confusing "`string1`" with `STDIN`.  `string1` (an argument; called `SET1` in GNU man page) is truncated, input is not.

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein: I seem to completely have misunderstood the meaning of 'to truncate'. I've commented on this under the answer below [and still don't get it].

Comment: @cellar.dweller : It might be better if you think of the the two args to `tr` as "sets" or "patterns" of characters and not strings.  Those corresponding sets/related patterns are used in the *translation* of the input.  So the `-t` in your example means that the first set is now only 3 characters, and that's applied in the translation, which is why the exact same example *without* `-t` does, in fact, produce different output.

Comment: @goldilocks may I shyly ask where this would make sense? An example maybe? I found quite some tutorials on `tr`, but hardly anyone seems to use `-t`

Comment: @cellar.dweller : Alright, I added that to the end of the answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When using tr -t command, string1 should be truncated to the length of string2, right?

Isn't that what happened?

```
abcdefghijklmn
123
```

Notice which letters are and are not swapped:

```
the 3ell1r is the s1fest pl13e
```

'a' and 'c', but not e, f, i, or l, which were in the original (non-truncated) set 1.

Without the `-t`, you get:

```
t33 33331r 3s t33 s133st p3133
```

This is because (from `man tr`), *"SET2 is extended to length of SET1 **by repeating its last character** as necessary."*  So without the `-t` to truncate set 1, what you have is the same as

```
tr abcdefhijklmn 1233333333333
```

Let's consider another example, but using the same "the cellar is the safest place" as input.

```
> input="the cellar is the safest place"
> echo $input | tr is X
the cellar XX the XafeXt place
```

This is because the 2nd set is automatically extended to cover all of the first set.  `-t` essentially *does the opposite of that*; it truncates the first set rather than extending the 2nd one:

```
> echo $input | tr -t is X
the cellar Xs the safest place
```

Which is the same as:

```
> echo $input | tr i X
the cellar Xs the safest place
```

Since the 's' was truncated from the first set.  If the two sets were the same length, then using `-t` won't make any difference:

```
> echo $input | tr is XY
the cellar XY the YafeYt place
> echo $input | tr -t is XY
the cellar XY the YafeYt place
```

Comment: [please note that this comment is a copy of the update that I made on the original post]. I thought `tr -t` means: *shorten string1 to the length of string2*. I see that `a` is translated to `1`, that `b` would be translated to `2` and that `c` is translated to `3`.
This has nothing to do with shortening. 'To truncate' seems to mean something different than I thought.

Comment: @cellar.dweller Truncate means to shorten, yes, but `tr` isn't short for *truncate*, it's short for *translate*.  The `-t` switch, however, is for truncating set 1 to the length of set 2 (and think: it would be meaningless the other way around). So, what I was trying to point out is that set 1 *has been shortened*: you get the exact same output as if you used `tr abc 123`.  Everything past c is no longer included in the translation.  I added a paragraph better explaining the difference between that and `tr abcdefhijklmn 123`.